# How do I get the token to switch a camera's relay using ONVIF library?

Tags: c#, onvif

I'm trying to set the camera's relay using the ONVIF library, but I can't get a token from the `GetRelayOutputs()` method.

I have seached several posts, but my problem must so simple that no one comments about it.

I have made a form with a single button for fast debbuging. Using the service reference https://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl I already can get time, date, url etc...

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DeviceClient deviceClient;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        var endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://172.16.2.119:8899/onvif/device_service");
        var httpTransportBinding = new HttpTransportBindingElement { AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Digest };
        var textMessageEncodingBinding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement { MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12, AddressingVersion.None) };
        var customBinding = new CustomBinding(textMessageEncodingBinding, httpTransportBinding);
        var passwordDigestBehavior = new PasswordDigestBehavior("admin", "admin");
        deviceClient = new DeviceClient(customBinding, endPointAddress);
        deviceClient.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(passwordDigestBehavior);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        var relay = deviceClient.GetRelayOutputs();
        deviceClient.SetRelayOutputState(relay.First().token, RelayLogicalState.active);
    }
}
```

The `DeviceClient` object is being initialised as expected, but when I try to get the relay's outputs, it gives me a empty array.

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong?
Is it possible to a camera that has a relay not being able to use it with ONVIF?

Thank you.

Comment: Documentation says this method has been depricated with version 2.0. What ver is implemented?

Comment: Hey, @terribletp, the library that I have posted is called "ONVIF Core" (v19.06), what suggests that it has the basic methods, right? There are some more specifications on https://www.onvif.org/profiles/specifications/. I have already tried the "DeviceIO" and got the same results.